# Trying to display posts but getting the pages as output

Tags: plugins, loop

I am trying to display the posts on my front page of the `roots theme's base.php` file.

I have added the loop as

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        echo '<h2>';
        the_title();
        echo '</h2>';
        the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

However, this keeps displaying just the content and title from the first page.

How do i get it to display the posts? I have set the number of posts as 3 under settings -> reading .

Comment: Please post more context for that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save it with a suitable name like:

- `home.php`
- `index.php`
- `archive.php`
- `category.php`

This link can help you: [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)